# Back button close modalview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an iPad application, with 3 `UIViewController`'s:
The first one contains a `UITableView`. On "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`" it opens a modal with the second `ViewController`, like that :

```
NavRapportViewController *nav=[[NavRapportViewController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[XAppDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In this second view there is a button to open the third view :

```
GalleryLayout *layout = [[GalleryLayout alloc] init];
GalleryViewController *gallery = [[GalleryViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];

[gallery setLegID:monLeg.legId];
gallery.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:gallery animated:YES];
```

Last, in the third view there is a back button. When I press the back button I supposed to return on the second view. But in practice, the second view appear during less than one second and the modal dismiss itself.

I've try to override the backButton action like that :

```
-(void)backPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:self.delegate animated:YES];
}
```

But the result is the same.

**Do you know why the modal close itself, and how should I do to keep it open ?**

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036963/ios-5-trying-to-pushviewcontroller-from-modal-view

Comment: why are you giving self.delegate then try this in your back button action  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

The second view controller is the root view controller of navigation controller. you can just pop to root view controller.

```
-(void)backPressed:(id)sender {

    //[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //OR

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just try this method but it doesn't work. The modal disappear.

Comment: code updated . [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; should work.verify and let me know